# Cannot convert 'str' object to bytes error in RSA python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encryption

I've been using **rsa** python library to encrypt and decrypt data, all is working fine.
However when I save the encrypted data to a CSV file using **pandas** and if try to decrypt the saved data value by extracting it from the CVS file, then it no longer works

Below is my python code

```
import rsa
import pandas as pd


key = int(input("enter an interger key value : ")) #512
paasword = input("input pass : ")

publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(key) 
encpass = rsa.encrypt(paasword.encode(),publicKey)

print("\noriginal string: ", paasword)
print("\nencrypted string: ", encpass)

# Save to New CSV file


data={'Name':['Jhon'], 'Password':[encpass], } #new dict
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # create new pandas DataFrame

df.to_csv('my_data.csv', index=False) # write a new csv file

# Extract form CSV file

df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv",index_col = 0) #using 0th column (Name) as index
find_password = df['Password']['Jhon'] #column id , index of that row;

print(find_password)

decpass = rsa.decrypt(find_password, privateKey).decode()
print("\ndecrypted string: ", decMessage)
```

```
> enter an integer key value: 512
> input pass: abhijeetbyte123

> original string:  abhijeetbyte123

> encrypted string:  b',.\x89\xb8&"\xdc|\x97.................................
```

```
> error : TypeError: cannot convert 'str' object to bytes
```

**What should I do to fix this error**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the "serialization" to a CSV file of the encrypted password. `encpass` is of type `bytes` but Pandas writes a literal string representation to the CSV file. Thus, Pandas will also read this back as a string (`"b'$\\xaa...'"`) which only looks similar to a bytes object.

If you want to write the password to a file, I suggest that you encode it with base64 and create a UTF-8 string representation of it. UTF-8 alone will most likely produce encoding errors for (pseudo-)random byte streams.

```
import rsa
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import pandas as pd


key = int(input("enter an interger key value : ")) #512
paasword = input("input pass : ")

publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(key) 
encpass = rsa.encrypt(paasword.encode(),publicKey)

print("\noriginal string: ", paasword)
print("\nencrypted string: ", encpass)

# Encode encrypted password to base64 and produce UTF-8 conform string
b64_enc_pass = b64encode(encpass).decode()

# Save to New CSV file
data={'Name':['Jhon'], 'Password':[b64_enc_pass], } #new dict
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # create new pandas DataFrame

df.to_csv('my_data.csv', index=False) # write a new csv file

# Extract form CSV file

df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv",index_col = 0) #using 0th column (Name) as index
find_password = df['Password']['Jhon'] #column id , index of that row;

# Decode encrypted password from UTF-8 encoded string
find_password = b64decode(find_password.encode())

print(find_password)

decpass = rsa.decrypt(find_password, privateKey).decode()
print("\ndecrypted string: ", decpass)
```

Comment: It works fine, **Thanks a lot**  .

 It saves a lot of my time and efforts